# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in D:\xampp\htdocs\ex_starts\ch04_ex1\delete_category.php on line 32

Tags: php

```
<?php

//Get ID
$category_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'category_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

//Validate inputs
if ($category_id == null || $category_id == false) {

$error = "Invalid category ID.";

include('error.php');

} else {

require_once('database.php');
// Delete the product from the database


$query = 'DELETE FROM categories

              WHERE categoryID = :category_id';

$statement = $db->prepare($query);

$statement->bindValue(':category_id', $category_id);

$statement->execute();

$statement->closeCursor();

// Display the Category List page
**include('category_list.php');**
```

** is line 32. I got error :

> syntax error, unexpected end of file in D:\xampp\htdocs\ex_starts\ch04_ex1\delete_category.php

Comment: Looks like you forgot the closing `}` of the `else`

Comment: For further info: [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)